# Starting nitrogen (erlang)

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I need some help starting nitrogen 2.1

This document (http:// nitrogenproject.com/doc/index.html) tells me to run ./deps/get_mochiweb.sh - but the deps folder contains no such script

> ls ../../deps
>
> nitrogen_core  nprocreg  simple_bridge  sync

These slides on the other hand: http:// nitrogenproject.com/doc/tutorial.html tell me to run

> ./bin/nitrogen console
>
> open http://localhost:8000

I seems more reasonable, but I don't quite get it. "./bin/nitrogen console" opens up an erlang console, but as far as i know "open http://localhost:8000" isn't erlang syntax. If i run i nothing happens. After I exit nothing is listing to port 8000

I'm not sure what to do from here

Comment: It probably tells you that you can test if Nitrogen is up and running just connecting to port `8000` via your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Once the application is running you have a web server listening on port 8000. Open a web browser and browse to localhost:8000.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting with Nitrogen, it might be better to run "quickstart.sh":

```
cd Quickstart
./quickstart.sh
```

Now point your browser to http://localhost:8000 and play with Nitrogen demos to get a hang of it.

Once you are ready to use Nitrogen for your project, you can build a release on top of yaws or mochiweb.